# Run a jQuery function when all knockout.js has rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to use jQuery to reorganise some of the layout of a page, however, the page templating is done using the Knockout JS which I am not familiar with...

I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("page has loaded!);
});
```

But this loads before the Knockout JS fully rendered.

I also tried:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() { 
    console.log("page has loaded!);
});
```

However, same situation. The knockout JS was not fully rendered.

**How do I know that page has fully rendered, including the knockout js?**

*Please note: I am not familiar with knockout js, never used it before so achieving it without changing any html or knockout js and using only jQuery would be the best.*

Comment: I am trying to understand it but it's just too much for me. All I want to do is write to console when document is ready... Uff, harder then I thought...

Comment: Knockout starts rendering when you call `ko.applyBindings`. This happens synchronously; no other work can be done in between. Meaning: the rendering is done on the line *after* `applyBindings`.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, I am having a good read and some hands on experience with knockout JS now and trying to get my head around it. It is a quiet difficult task anyway :)